# Dynamically Update Stylesheet Reference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to dynamically alter my stylesheet link in my masterpage.

I have the code below but the css isn't displaing correctly and the outputed HTML looks like below..

**Outputed HTML**

```
<link href="../Content/%3C%25=c.Area_Name%20%25%3E.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Stylesheet reference**

```
<% foreach (var c in (IEnumerable<Categories>)ViewData["Categories"]) { %>
<link href="../../Content/<%=c.Area_Name %>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<% } %>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: &lt;% =c.... might give you a different result.

Comment: Do you have <head runat="server"> in your masterpage code?

Comment: Yes I have <head runat="server"> on my MasterPage.

Comment: This will work: `<% foreach (var c in (IEnumerable<Category>)ViewData["Categories"]) { Response.Write("<link href=\"../../Content/" + c.AreaName + ".css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />"); }%>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't put <%= %> code inside the head tag. Try the same code you did outside the heads tag.

Comment: The problem is that I need to modify the Stylesheet reference in the head tag. What LukLed says above did work, not sure if this is the best way around the problem though?

Answer (score 0):

In markup place link with run at

```
<link runat="server" id="lnkCss1" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="print, projection, screen"/>
```

In code use

```
((HtmlLink)FindControl("lnkCss1")).Attributes["href"] = ResolveUrl("~/Css/YourCss.css");
```

Another solution is to dynamically add HtmlLink link without using link tag in markup.

Comment: Thanks Priyan, when you say 'In code use' where exactly would that code need to go?

Comment: In page load of page/master page

Comment: I don't think I have a page behind in asp.net mvc.